# Кодировка сообщений

Tags: php, кодировка, dle

Всем привет. Добавил дополнительные поля для обратной связи **dle** с помощью этого **[хака](http://techno-co.ru/datalife_engine/hak/1331-dobavlyaem-svoi-polya-v-obratnuyu-svyaz-dle.html)**

Вроде бы все хорошо. Отправляешь сообщение - и информация **только** с этих полей отображается кракозябрами. Сам сайт имеет кодировку **windows-1251**, пробовал перекодировать эти файлы в windows-1251 через notepad++ - результата не дало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем менять кодировку файлов?!

Тебе надо менять кодировку отправляемого текста. 
В php кодировка меняется при помощи функции **iconv()**, её описание: http://www.php.su/iconv()

*П.С. Если для проверки кодировки строки будешь использовать функцию mb_detect_encoding, то знай - она не работает. Т.е. если ты перекодируешь строку в windows-1251 и потом вызовешь mb_detect_encoding, то она тебе покажет utf8. Но на самом деле строка будет в нужной тебе кодировке ;)*

Comment: Я в php слабоват, подскажи, пожалуйста, как эту функцию подогнать для этого:

    $gaf = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['gaf'] ));

    $gaf = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['gaf'] ));

    $row['template'] = str_replace( "{%gaf%}", $gaf, $row['template'] );

Answer (score 1):

```
$gaf = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['gaf'] ));
$gaf = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['gaf'] ));
$row['template'] = str_replace( "{%gaf%}", $gaf, $row['template'] );
$row['template'] = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $row['template']);
```

Comment: Сделал вот так, **$row['template'] = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $gaf);** - сообщение приходит пустое

Comment: А что вы отправляете? Сообщение на почту при помощи функции mail()?

Comment: Суть в следующем: любой сервис отправки почтовых сообщений или смс-ок имеет четкие(прописанные) требования к кодировке сообщения. Возможно вы пытаетесь отправить почту/смску в кодировке, которая не поддерживается сервисом отправки!